# c# how to access unallocated memory

Tags: c#

In C# book is written that I'm unable to access unallocated memory. They said that is possible in unsafe context. My question is how this can be done? 
I tried something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    unsafe
    {
        int c;
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }            
}
```

With allow unsafe option in project properties. And this code is unable to compile.

Comment: Wanna play to the Russian roulette maybe? Using C#, then access to the unallocated memory (or anything like that) is much like making off-road with a Lambo...

Comment: No, I'm only curious. If there is an option i like to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unsafe` keyword does not completely alter the language or compilation model, you still need to initialize any variables before using them. If you want to access "unallocated memory", you need to get a pointer to that memory. Here is an example:

```
unsafe void AccessMemory()
{
    const int address = 10000;
    byte[] array = new byte[0];
    fixed (byte* zero = array)
    {
        byte* p = zero + address;
    }
}
```

Here we get a pointer to the empty array, which gives the zero pointer. Then we offset that pointer by some amount (address), which results in a pointer to that memory address.